# Angular | Easier way to cross-component communicate?

Tags: angular

I know there's too much posts out there about how to communicate between components.

And I know that there are basically 3 ways here:

- Passing the reference of one component to another
- Communication through parent component
- Communication through Service

If I have no no parent/child/sister relation between two components the only way I see is through a service. However: it feels extremely wrong for the following example:

```
<my-navbar></myNavbar>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

This would be the structure insite the `<app-root>` element

I want my navbar to have a different style when navigating to `/home` which is then being loaded by the router as a element next to the `<router-outlet>`

Currently I do this by calling a service function in the `ngOnInit` method of `/home` that sets a bool which binded to a class inside the `my-navbar`component.

It feels wrong to use a service for that.

I know that I could create an event-handler inside `<my-navbar>` which is triggered by the router when a spedific route is active. But I have some other situations that are independend from the router, so Im looking for a more general solution.

What would be the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: A service really is the best way. In the example above, that would be using the router service, and subscribing to the routing events, in other scenarios you may need to create your own Observable. It really depends on the use case

Comment: In your case, my-navbar only depends of the "url", so is better subscribe to ActivateRouter.url https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#activatedroute